# SQL Server / .NET - Get the connection pool size

Tags: sql-server, connection-pooling

I have an application which performs a series of tasks across many threads. When each thread has done its unit of work it saves it to a SQL Server database by spawning a new thread and then terminating (this is because the worker threads are limited to about 10, but I never encountered a limit for SQL server connection threads until now...)

Lately I've been hitting use-cases where there are so many SQL server connections that the pool is too large and the SQL Server client complains and then dies.

I can control my SQL server connection-owning threads and have them wait until other connections in the pool have returned, however I have to know how many connections are allowed first, but all of the information I can find is about how to set the pool size, not how to get it.

Comment: The pool can grow to a point where you can keep a fairly heavy system busy.  Instead of looking at the pool, consider verifying that you're not leaking connections.  Also reduce the amount of time a connection is kept open to an absolute minimum: call a stored procedure, and release right after.

Comment: I'm with Andomar, you have a performance issue here. Don't fix the symptoms, fix the root cause.

Comment: Each thread does about 1000 INSERT operations and then returns. Connections are kept open for as short at time as possible, but I've found when I've got over 100 threads, all doing about 1000 INSERTs all at the same time the exception is thrown. Thus the only solution is to introduce some kind of semaphore-count block for the threads, but I need to find out the right maximum value for the semaphore. Hence my question.